Analytic Continuation of the Riemann Zeta Function via Contour Integration
I've read a number of zeta function related texts and questions on forums like this and I still do not understand some parts of how $\zeta$ is analytically (meromorphically) continued using contour integration as Riemann did. I understand that $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges for $\Re(s)>1$ and that Dirichlet's Eta function can be used to analytically continue it to $\Re(s)>0$.
The Hankel contour is often mentioned in relation to this topic. I see it as part of a keyhole contour, $C$, for the function: $$\frac{z^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^z-1}$$ Taking the branch cut to lie along the positive real axis, if we orient the keyhole contour positively (anticlockwise) and examine the integral over the Hankel contour $\mathcal{H}$, we get the following:$$\int_{\mathcal{H}} \frac{z^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^z-1} \mathrm{d}z = (1-\mathrm{e}^{2\pi is}) \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x-1} \mathrm{d}x  - \int_\gamma \frac{z^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^z-1} \mathrm{d}z$$
The two integrals on the RHS converge for $\Re(s)>1$, where the integral over $\gamma$ is the infinitesimal circle around the origin. I get confused around here. If we want to apply the residue theorem, we require a closed contour. A circle of radius $R$ completes the keyhole contour, an integral which only converges for $\Re(s)<0$. Applying the residue theorem gives $2(2\pi i)^s \zeta(1-s)$ as the value of the integral over $C$. This, however, also only converges for $\Re(s)<0$.
We can write an equality by separating the terms into some which converge for $\Re(s)>1$ and others which converge for $\Re(s)<0$. I get that the essence of analytic continuation is to extend the domain of definition but these two regions have no overlap, a condition which is required for an analytic continuation. It makes more sense to me in the context of Eta as we have already got convergence for $\zeta$ when $\Re(s)>0$ however the literature often makes this jump without mention of Eta which leaves me wondering as to how this is justified. This is likely due to a basic misunderstanding on my part of some of the concepts at play here but I appreciate any help that I'm offered.

The functional equation $$\zeta(s)=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)$$ allows one to determine $\zeta(s)$ from $\zeta(1-s)$ and vice-versa for $s\in\mathbb{C}$, but using formulas such as $$\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_n^\infty \frac{1}{n^s},,\quad\Re(s)>1$$ and $$\zeta(s)=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(1-s)  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1-s}},,\quad\Re(s)<0$$ provide no insight into the values of $\zeta(s)$ for $0<\Re(s)<1$ even though the functional equation is still valid in this range.
